# Pull to refresh with custom listview header (fixed header)

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I'm trying to implement Pull to refresh in my sherlockListFragment with this library [Pull to refresh library](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh/wiki/ListFragment)

I add for listview a cutom header. the problem when i try to fo make this header fixed . Pull to refresh i found this error in logcat:

```
 05-09 09:09:43.476: E/AndroidRuntime(22559): java.lang.IllegalStateException: **Can't be used with a custom content view** 05-09 09:09:43.476: E/AndroidRuntime(22559): at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.setListShown(ListFragment.java:282) 05-09 09:09:43.476: E/AndroidRuntime(22559):    at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.setListShown(ListFragment.java:258) 05-09 09:09:43.476: E/AndroidRuntime(22559):     at com.openbee.v3.fragments.NotifsFileFragment.onRefreshStarted(NotifsFileFragment.java:355)
```

How can resolve this problem an inregrate pull to refresh with custom content view. there is my code :

NotifsFileFragment:

```
public class NotifsFileFragment extends SherlockListFragment  implements OnRefreshListener {
public static  ActionMode mActionMode;

private static Notifs_file_adapter adapter;

public static  ArrayList<DocumentRow> itemData;
private static final String TAG_COLOR = "color";

private RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
private ImageView mImageView;

private Drawable icon_header_Drawable;
int selectednumber;
private PullToRefreshLayout mPullToRefreshLayout;
View listvView;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container,
            savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_queue, container, false);
    mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon_header_list);
    listvView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
    icon_header_Drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_header_notif_file);
    mImageView.setImageDrawable(icon_header_Drawable);
    TextView mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_header);
    mTextView.setText("Notifications des documents");
    //  setListShownNoAnimation(true);
    return view;
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view,savedInstanceState);
    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;

    // As we're using a ListFragment we create a PullToRefreshLayout manually
    mPullToRefreshLayout = new PullToRefreshLayout(viewGroup.getContext());

    // We can now setup the PullToRefreshLayout
    ActionBarPullToRefresh.from(getActivity())
    // We need to insert the PullToRefreshLayout into the Fragment's ViewGroup
    .insertLayoutInto(viewGroup)
    // Here we mark just the ListView and it's Empty View as pullable
    .theseChildrenArePullable(android.R.id.list, android.R.id.empty)
    .listener(this)
    .setup(mPullToRefreshLayout);
}
```

Comment: were you able to figure this out?